# Dividing One Column By Another Returns NAN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, division

I have two dataframes. See the picture. [image: DATAFRAMES] I am trying to divide the sum in df (df['Sum']) by the hours worked (df2['hours_worked'])

however this code...`

```
df['Kits/Hour'] = df['Sum']/df2['hours_worked']
```

returns a column with all NAN. Not sure why this is occurring. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure they have same `index`

```
df['Kits/Hour'] = df['Sum']/df2.set_index('person')['hours_worked']
```